# Facebook login scope email doesn't work

Tags: email, facebook-login

I have implement facebook login on my website and I ask for email permission.
In SOME cases, I can't get the email address... But with some facebook accounts, it works...

Here my code :

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: response,
            url: $('.facebookConnectUrl').text(),
            success: function (data, text) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    if (redirectPageAfterLogin === undefined) {
                        location.reload();
                    } else if (redirectPageAfterLogin == 'add') {
                        window.location.replace($('.header .li_sell a').attr('href'));
                    }
                    $.fancybox.close();
                } else {
                    $('.waitForConnexion').hide();
                    $('.errorConnexionFB').show();

                    $('.errorFacebookRegister').click();
                }
```

//                  $(document).css('cursor','default');
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
//                  alert(error);
                }
            });
//          console.log(response);
        });

Console.log give me that :

```
birthday: "03/23/1990"
first_name: "Mathieu"
gender: "male"
id: "100004609354200"
last_name: "XXXX"
link: "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx"
locale: "fr_FR"
name: "Mathieu XXXX"
timezone: 1
updated_time: "2012-10-28T12:10:39+0000"
username: "xxxxxx"
```

In Facebook application details (in french) :

```
Cette application a besoin de (this app need)   
Vos infos de base (your basics informations)
Votre adresse électronique (xxxxx@yahoo.fr) (your email address)
Votre anniversaire (your birthdate)
```

Comment: For the x-th time: Not every Facebook user _has_ an email address deposited with Facebook, since users can also use their mobile to sign up …

Comment: Yes but, with my account, I've sign up with email (please see my post)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same failure ... Were you able to solve it?
greetings

Comment: I found a solution for my error... I had an invalid email address for facebook. I changed my email address to a @live.com and now it works.